# Passing parameter to bean's method in camel blueprint

Tags: apache-camel

I'm trying to call bean's public method by passing parameter .But i'm unable to run it.Here is my sample blueprint code(I have written `from` clause but here i'm pasting only necessary code)-

```
  <bean id="ProcessorRef" class="com.healthedge.customer.THC.extractor.ProcessorClass">

  <to uri="bean:ProcessorRef" />
```

Processor class-

```
public class ProcessorClass{
    public String whatAmI(String str) {
            return "I am "+str;
        }
}
```

Now in above example how can I invoke `whatAmI` method with parameter from blueprint?TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value you want to pass to whatAmI method is in header, you can do like this.

```
<to uri="bean:ProcessorRef?method=whatAmI(${header.xyz})" />
```

If its a constant string, you can put the string directly in place of `${header.xyz}`

Another option is to modify your whatAmI method to

```
public class ProcessorClass{
    public String whatAmI(Exchange exchange) {
            // exchange has many methods, with which you can access headers and body.
        }
}
```

In such a case you can write the route like this

```
<to uri="bean:ProcessorRef?method=whatAmI" />
```

Personally, I would prefer second option, because it gives you access to complete exchange object, which would have all the details.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it by calling directly the method you want

```
<bean id="ProcessorRef" class="com.healthedge.customer.THC.extractor.ProcessorClass">

<bean ref="ProcessorRef" method="whatAmI('your_parameter_here')" />
```